# why intersection of two RDD does not work in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have two custom class RDD and I know that they have some intersect but when I use Intersection method Nothing returned. Why is this happen and How can I solve this? Am I miss something? Here is what I did:

```
List <Person> p = new ArrayList<> ();
p.add(new Person(1,"hh","a@b.com","Male"));
p.add(new Person(2,"hh","a@b.com","Male"));

JavaRDD<Person> person1 = sc.parallelize(p);
JavaRDD<Person> person2 = sc.parallelize(p);
System.out.println(person1.intersection(person2).count()); //returns 0.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement equals and hash code for Person class.